# Prevent child process from inheriting parent's environment

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have the following 2 scenarios with a command `doSomething` which runs in the background and uses an env variable VAR. I have assigned the correct value for the variable in ~/.bash_profile.

1) When run from the bash prompt with `$doSomething &` : Things work fine since the correct value of VAR is used.

2) When run from inside a shell script : The shell script has itself been invoked as part of a process cycle that has altered the value of VAR and exported. When I call `$doSomething &` inside the shell script, it uses the new value of VAR and fails. That makes sense since the command inherits the environment for the script. Is there a way I can invoke the command such that it uses the values in bash_profile?

It seems that one option could be to use `env -u` to unset the altered value and reassign the value in bash_profile. Is there a better way?

Thanks !

Comment: No, that's the way it's _supposed_ to work.

Comment: why not just `source ~/.bash_profile` in your child script..?

Comment: Either using `env` or being explicit of the variables when running your command (ie.: `LC_ALL=C OtherVar=foo doSomething &`).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to put the variable definition into a separate file, like:

*var.sh*

```
export VAR="value"
```

Then source that file form inside your `.bashrc` and from your script:

```
source /path/to/var.sh
```

Putting the variable definition into a separate file has the advantage that you don't need to source the whole `.bashrc` from inside your script which might lead to unwanted side effects.